# Writing a bash loop to check differences in file size in loop

Tags: linux, bash, email

I am writing a continuous bash loop to check for new mail in the /var/spool/mail file.  This script needs to be continuous and compares the size of the previous loop. If the size increases then it needs to echo something. This is what I have now.  It is not echoing anything when I run it.  I am not sure if it is picking up the difference in the size of the file. To run it you need to input ./"the name of the script"  /var/spool/mail/user

```
#!/bin/bash
checkUsage()
{
while true
do
sleep 10
fileSize=$(stat -c%s $1)
        sleep 5;
        fileSizeNew=$(stat -c%s $1)

        if [ "$fileSize" -lt "$fileSizeNew" ]
        then
           echo -e  "[Notice : ] $USER you have mail!!!"
           exit 
        fi

done
}
checkUsage $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
checkUsage()
{
fileSize=$(stat -c%s $1)
while true;     do
        sleep 10
        fileSizeNew=$(stat -c%s $1)
        if [ "$fileSize" -lt "$fileSizeNew" ]; then
                echo -e  "[Notice : ] $USER you have mail!!!"
           exit 
        fi

done
}
checkUsage $1
```

The problem with your current code is that you're only really checking for a difference in file size during the 5 seconds of the second sleep. Meaning that you'd re-declare fileSize every 10 seconds, then wait 5 seconds and re-declare fileSizeNew and compare them (Mind the 5 second gap).

In my example, you declare fileSize once because it's sitting outside of the while loop, so every 10 seconds we'll take a look at the new size and compare it to the old - ever lasting original file size.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I came up with a new script.  My problem with this is that after it echoes out the file size 2 times if nothing changed in /var/spool/mail/$USER it freezes.  I need it to not do that and compare the size from old to new continuously.  I do not know how to do that

Comment: This is my new code.                                                                            #!/bin/bash
sleep 15;
filename=/var/spool/mail/will
filesize="$(du -b "$filename")"
filesizeold="${filesize//[!0-9]/}"
echo $filesizeold
sleep 10;
filename=/var/spool/mail/will
filesize="$(du -b "$filename")"
filesizenew="${filesize//[!0-9]/}"
echo $filesizenew
while true  
do
if [ $filesizeold -ne $filesizenew ];
then 
        break
fi
done
echo "$USER, You have

Comment: Adding the whole script to the comments isn't going to work. If this is a separate problem, please do go ahead and ask a new question, if it's the same one, just edit the original question to resemble whatever scenario you might've missed in the first place.